# SQL Retain or Running total

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I have a table where I have a list of Stores and want to order them by amount of distribution and then for each store I want to get the highest distribution first and continue to total until I hit a certain amount like 60% and then trigger a field (ETA60) to true for all of those records.

So my table would look something like this.

[image: Table Example]

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I want to order by Store (DIVLOC not shown I know) and then by Distri (Distribution).  The tract order does not matter it just happens I did that.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You want a running sum and some `case` logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(distr1) over (partition by store order by tract) - distr1 >= 0.6
             then 'X'
        end) as eta60
from t;
```

Comment: --Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Select DIVLOC, TRACTID, Distribution Into [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] from [GEO].[TRACTS_WITH_CREDITDATA__ETA_True_D2019_V2020]
ALTER TABLE [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] ADD ETA60 Bit DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
select [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] .*,
       (case when sum(Distribution) over (partition by divloc order by DIVLOC, Distribution) - Distribution >= 0.6
             then 1
        end) as eta60
from [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing];

Select * From [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] Order by divloc, Distribution

Comment: @Bearcatrunner . . . This syntax works in all supported versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of window function to filter the record:

```
SELECT x.store, x.tract, x.distri, x.eta as eta60 from 
(SELECT a.*, coalesce(SUM(distri) OVER(PARTITION BY store 
ORDER BY tract rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ), distri) as eta60,
coalesce(SUM(distri) OVER(PARTITION BY store 
ORDER BY tract rows unbounded preceding ), distri) as eta
FROM
table_dist a) x WHERE coalesce(eta60, distri) <= 60;
```

If you dont want to filter and just mark such records with some flag 'X' then you can use below query:

```
SELECT a.*, case when coalesce(SUM(distri) OVER(PARTITION BY store 
ORDER BY tract rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ), distri) <= 60 THEN 'X' END as eta60 FROM
table_dist a;
```

Comment: --Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Select DIVLOC, TRACTID, Distribution Into [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] from [GEO].[TRACTS_WITH_CREDITDATA__ETA_True_D2019_V2020]
ALTER TABLE [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] ADD ETA60 Bit DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
select [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] .*,
       (case when sum(Distribution) over (partition by divloc order by DIVLOC, Distribution) - Distribution >= 0.6
             then 1
        end) as eta60
from [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing];

Select * From [aTemp].[TRACTS_WITH_CD_ETA_Testing] Order by divloc, Distribution